# Writing variable length data in Excel file from Matlab

Tags: excel, matlab

I am trying to create a excel file from Matlab with data for multiple cases. The excel file should look something like this:

```
Case #|____________________________Line 1_____________________________________________|_______ Line 2 _____________ ...
      |______Node 1______|______Node 2______|______Node 3______|...|______OverAll_____|
      | Min|Max|Mean|Std | Min|Max|Mean|Std | Min|Max|Mean|Std |...| Min|Max|Mean|Std |
      |_______________________________________________________________________________|
     1|    |   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
     2|    |   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
```

I have the data for each Line>Node in a structured format which I can read through a for loop for a given case. How can I write the values in an excel file? I don't know how to get the next available cell range where I need to place the value. Also, how can I generate such header text dynamically. The number of Nodes and properties (Min/Max/Mean/Std) might change in future.

Thank you for your help. Any suitable tutorial which teaches little advanced xlswrite commands will also help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Activexserver to import whole Excel Functionality in MATLAB using

```
hApp = actxserver('Excel.Application')
```

Rest you can use all methods available to Excel Application in MATLAB

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, I was able to write excel file just using `xlswrite` command with providing correct column name. The column name is created using another function which converts column number to respective excel column name (1 = A, 2 = B etc. ) . But, then I found that creating excel file is very slow and since I need large data analysis method, I switched to writing a CSV file instead.